# How to set Session.Timeout

Tags: asp.net, session

In ASP.NET application's web.config, I have something like this

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30"/>
```

1. Is this the only place where Sessions timeouts are defined
2. Is this timeoout in web.config the only one for all the sessions in the application.
3. Can I not set the session timeouts for each session individually.
4. IF so, where??
5. I am looking to use "Keep me Logged-in", where do I have to set the timeout to Maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "Keep me logged in" goes across sessions, I would set a cookie with an expiry date of a day or a week. Log them in automatically if the cookie exists, or redirect to the login page.

You can set session timeouts in the `web.config` file as you have described, or in the `Global.asax` file's `Session.Start()` function. For example:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Timeout = 30;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The keep me logged in has nothing to do with session length, but with the lifetime of the [Forms Authentication Cookie](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443).